# How to merge two objects within array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects like this. I want to merge this if year and DName is smae. Here is my array

```
var film = [{
    Year:2017
    DName:"Rohit"
    Released:"Golmal"
    id:0
},
{
    Year:2017
    DName:"Rohit"
    Upcoming:"Singham"
    id:1
},
{
    Year:2016
    DName:"Anil"
    Released:"xyz"
    id:2
},
{
    Year:2017
    DName:"David"
    Released:"Judva"
    id:3
},
{
    Year:2018
    DName:"Karan"
    InProgress:"Brahmastra"
    id:4
},
{
    Year:2017
    DName:"David"
    InProgress:"Something"
    id:5
}]
```

Now in this json I want if `year and DName` is same then object shout merge. Output shoud be like

```
[{
    Year:2017
    DName:"Rohit"
    Released:"Golmal",
    Upcoming:"Singham"
    id:0
},
{
    Year:2016
    DName:"Anil"
    Released:"xyz"
    id:2
},
{
    Year:2017
    DName:"David"
    Released:"Judva",
    InProgress:"Something"
    id:3
},
{
    Year:2018
    DName:"Karan"
    InProgress:"Brahmastra"
    id:4
}]
```

I was trying to merge object but I am failing how to do in loop.

Does anyone have a script for this or any built in method to achive this?

The which I tried here is

```
ww function(destination,source) {
    for (var property in source)
        destination[property] = source[property];
    return destination;
}
```

Now in this case I can pass two objects, but for an array I am not sure how to pass.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but did you tried anything yourself first? Please share your attempt.

Comment: Add your tried code

Comment: @gurvinder372 I tried to post the code but editor is telling too much code and then I removed, I will update my question.

Comment: @gurvinder372 I updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a hash table which keeps the reference to the objects with same `Year` and `DName`. Then update all properties and return a new array.

```js
var film = [{ Year: 2017, DName: "Rohit", Released: "Golmal", id: 0 }, { Year: 2017, DName: "Rohit", Upcoming: "Singham", id: 1 }, { Year: 2016, DName: "Anil", Released: "xyz", id: 2 }, { Year: 2017, DName: "David", Released: "Judva", id: 3 }, { Year: 2018, DName: "Karan", InProgress: "Brahmastra", id: 4 }, { Year: 2017, DName: "David", InProgress: "Something", id: 5 }],
    hash = {},
    result = [];

film.forEach(function (o) {
    function update(source, target) {
        Object.keys(source).forEach(function (k) { target[k] = source[k]; });
    }

    var key = ['Year', 'DName'].map(function (k) { return o[k] }).join('|');
    if (!(key in hash)) {
        hash[key] = {};
        result.push(hash[key]);
    }
    update(o, hash[key]);
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6 with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
var film = [{ Year: 2017, DName: "Rohit", Released: "Golmal", id: 0 }, { Year: 2017, DName: "Rohit", Upcoming: "Singham", id: 1 }, { Year: 2016, DName: "Anil", Released: "xyz", id: 2 }, { Year: 2017, DName: "David", Released: "Judva", id: 3 }, { Year: 2018, DName: "Karan", InProgress: "Brahmastra", id: 4 }, { Year: 2017, DName: "David", InProgress: "Something", id: 5 }],
    hash = new Map,
    result = [];

film.forEach(function (o) {
    var key = ['Year', 'DName'].map(k => o[k]).join('|');
    if (!hash.has(key)) {
        hash.set(key, {});
        result.push(hash.get(key));
    }
    Object.assign(hash.get(key), o);
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *array.reduce*, *array.find* and *Object.assign*:

```js
var film = [{
    Year:2017,
    DName:"Rohit",
    Released:"Golmal",
    id:0
},
{
    Year:2017,
    DName:"Rohit",
    Upcoming:"Singham",
    id:1
},
{
    Year:2016,
    DName:"Anil",
    Released:"xyz",
    id:2
},
{
    Year:2017,
    DName:"David",
    Released:"Judva",
    id:3
},
{
    Year:2018,
    DName:"Karan",
    InProgress:"Brahmastra",
    id:4
},
{
    Year:2017,
    DName:"David",
    InProgress:"Something",
    id:5
}];

var film = film.reduce((m, o) => {
    var found = m.find(p => p.Year === o.Year && p.DName === o.DName);        
    if (found) {
        var foundId = found.id;  // Save id, it will be overwritten by Object.assign
        Object.assign(found, o);
        found.id = foundId;      // restore id
    } else {
        m.push(o);
    }
    return m;
}, []);

console.log(film);
```